# Angular-cli many modules

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm developing an application using angular-cli interface. Unfortunately, right now there are no commands like:

```
ng generate module featureModule
```

So I have to create module manually. How can I add a module to an application generated by angular-cli and what practises are best to do it?

Angular's version: 2.0.0-rc.4

Comment: The thing is that now angular-cli supports RC.4 version of angular. I've to update to RC.5 using this guide https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/rc4-to-rc5.html. After I'll be able to create modules with @NgModule.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is propose a pull request to [angular-cli on github](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli).

Take a look at how component generation is implemented for an example:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/tree/master/addon/ng2/blueprints/component

Also check this link from there docs for a few hints on updating the repo:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#development-hints-for-hacking-on-angular-cli

Comment: You, possbible didn't understood me correct. The question was not how to implement such command in angular-cli, the problem is to do it (add module) manually in project generated by angular-cli. I''ll correct the question to avoid misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

Now angular-cli supports RC.4 version of angular. I've to update to RC.5 using this guide angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/rc4-to-rc5.html. After I'll be able to create modules with @NgModule.